# Use nested if or and

Tags: python

Is there a difference in speed between these options?

```py
a, b, c = True, int(), 'Hello World!'

if a:
    if isinstance(b, int):
        if c == 'Hello World!':
            pass
```

```py
a, b, c = True, int(), 'Hello World!'

if (
    a
    and isinstance(b, int)
    and c == 'Hello World!'
):
    pass
```

Provided that there will be no else statements

Comment: Why wouldn't you write these on one line?

Comment: readability (...)

Comment: Yes, `if a and isinstance(b, int) and c == 'Hello World!':` is more readable than either of your options. If your condition is much more complicated then you can write it in a separate function and just write `if my_condition(a, b, c):`

Comment: Yeah the statements would be quite a bit more complicated than this, but I wouldnt know how to put that in an example. Also didnt know I couldnt ask opinion based questions

Comment: agreed, both your approaches are too convoluted. One of the [tenats of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2) is "Flat is better than nested", and have to agree that it's definitely the right thing in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise, they both generate the same bytecode:

```
import dis

a, b = 1, 2

def nested():
    if a:
        if b:
            pass

def _and():
    if a and b:
        pass

dis.dis(nested)
print('***********************************')
dis.dis(_and)
```

outputs

```
 6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

  7           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

  8     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
***********************************
 11           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

 12     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Visually, using `and` has the advantage of using only one indentation level, especially if written as a single line (even `black` prefers that):

```
if a and isinstance(b, int) and c == "Hello World!":
```

If you have too many conditions to fit on a single line, just move the check to a function:

```
def should_do_it():
    return a and isinstance(b, int) and c == "Hello World!"

if should_do_it():
    pass
```